# Custom template filter and query

Tags: django

I'm attempting to get all active employees using a template filter, but I'm not having much luck. I was wondering if you might know why.

models.py

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

My template filter is as follows:

```
@register.filter
def active_employees(model_instances):
    return model_instances.filter(active=False)
```

template.html

```
    {% if request.user.employee.all|active_employees|length > 0 %} 

        There is an active employee

    {% endif %}
```

The error I get is as follows:

```
Invalid filter: 'actual_employees'
```

Comment: Error might be because of the filter file name.

Comment: removed underscore. same issue. sorry

Comment: pls share project structure and complete html  code.

Answer (score 0):

Few points that can help you debug the problem:

As per django documentation Your custom tags and filters will live in a module inside the **templatetags** directory. The name of the module file is the name you’ll use to load the tags later, so be careful to pick a name that won’t clash with custom tags and filters in another app.

For example, if your custom tags/filters are in a file called poll_extras.py, your app layout might look like this:

[image: polls/ init.py models.py templatetags/ init.py poll_extras.py views.py]

Check your project structure.

**And in your template you would use the following to load custom tag library:**

```
{% load poll_extras %}
```

Also this line  check logic if it should be True or False as i think active=True for active employees is correct condition rest depends on you implementation.

```
return model_instances.filter(active=False)
```

Notice the name django is complaining is **Invalid filter: 'actual_employees'** which is not present in your filter definition kindly cross check the same if it is present in your html or not as defined filter name is **active_employees**.